# spawn is not able to launch global package in node.js

Tags: node.js

I need to launch globally installed node package as a separate process through another global package called launcher. I want launcher to launch the another package and exit.

spawn is able to launch notepad as separate process. But not able to launch globally installed package.

I have written the below code:

```
//var child = moduleLauncher.spawn('notepad',[],{

var child = moduleLauncher.spawn('hrm_module C:/test.scanRequest',[],{

           detached: true,

           stdio: ['ignore', out, err] 
});

child.unref();
```

Generated Error:

```
events.js:154

  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: spawn hrm_module C:/test.scanRequest ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:475:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:389:17)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:449:11)
    at startup (node.js:140:18)
    at node.js:1001:3
```

Note: the commond - `hrm_module C:/test.scanRequest` is working fine on command prompt of windows.

I want to run this command through a launcher.

Answer (score 0):

```
spawn('hrm_module C:/test.scanRequest',[]
```

needs to be

```
spawn('hrm_module',['C:/test.scanRequest']
```

Pass the arguments in the argument array. Otherwise it will look for a file named `hrm_module C:/test.scanRequest` and not find one as you have found.

Comment: I tried as suggesting.. getting the below error: Error: spawn hrm_module ENOENT

Comment: Is the global `bin` directory where `hrm_module` would be on the PATH? Or is `hrm_module` just a module that doesn't have an command-line? If it's a module that doesn't appear in the bin directory then you could use: `spawn(require.resolve('hrm_module'),` to get the full path to the module.

Answer (score 0):

Let `cmd` to start the module for you:

```
const command = 'cmd';
const args = ['/C', 'hrm_module', 'C:/test.scanRequest']
const options = {/* your spawn options */ };
spawn(command, args, options);
```